# Need help on Bootstrap button group style

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap, servicenow

I am currently working on Servicenow Service Portal on the HTML pane i have written below script which is working perfectly fine but the button group is not so consistent

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- your widget template -->
  

  
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
  
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
      
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
          
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
       
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

And the output is as shown below, Tablet and smartphone is side by side how to make those as separate dropdown options, I tried adding break tag but the display is not so good can anyone please suggest how to resolve this

[image]

[image]

Comment: i added the last bootstrap cdn to your snippet and all work, which version do you use?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini it actually works but size became very small and i see 2 drop down icons. I will paste the output in the question please review

Comment: Change snippet with all your current code.

Comment: Yes i did that, after copying all your code it is resizing smaller and i see 2 drop down icons

Comment: No you don't understand, if you run your current snippet all work, so you didn't past all code in old snippet. change the current snippet for debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, you are using an older version of bootstrap.
Please update them.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>
<!-- your widget template -->
  

  
  
  <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-md btn-table">

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
  
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">2</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
      
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
          
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">3</th>
    <td>Larry</td>
    <td>the Bird</td>
    <td>
       
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sony</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" >
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tablet</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Smartphone</a>
  </div>
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Mahender Kvs, it is working but i am getting 2 drop down as shown in the question

Comment: but ur snippet is perfect, it is showing only one caret. did you add something to your code locally?

Answer (score 0):

CSS is your friend here. Declare a style, such as:

```
.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item { display:block; }
```